# Improving for loop - Trying to compare 2 lists of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, lemmatization

I'll try to make myself as clear as possible: I have 50k tweets I would like to do text mining on, and I'd like to improve my code. The data look like below (`sample_data`).

I'm interested in lemmatizing the words I have cleaned and tokenized (which are the values of the `twToken` keys)

```
sample_data = [{'twAuthor': 'Jean Lassalle',
                'twMedium': 'iPhone',
                'nFav': None,
                'nRT': '33',
                'isRT': True,
                'twText': ' RT @ColPeguyVauvil : @jeanlassalle "allez aux bouts de vos rêves" ',
                'twParty': 'Résistons!',
                'cleanText': ' rt colpeguyvauvil jeanlassalle allez aux bouts de vos rêves ',
                'twToken': ['colpeguyvauvil', 'jeanlassalle', 'allez', 'bouts', 'rêves']},
               {'twAuthor': 'Jean-Luc Mélenchon',
                'twMedium': 'Twitter Web Client',
                'nFav': '806',
                'nRT': '375',
                'isRT': False,
                'twText': ' (2/2) Ils préfèrent créer une nouvelle majorité cohérente plutôt que les alliances à géométrie variable opportunistes de leur direction. ',
                'twParty': 'La France Insoumise',
                'cleanText': ' 2 2 ils préfèrent créer une nouvelle majorité cohérente plutôt que les alliances à géométrie variable opportunistes de leur direction ',
                'twToken': ['2', '2', 'préfèrent', 'créer', 'nouvelle', 'majorité', 'cohérente', 'plutôt', 'alliances', 'géométrie', 'variable', 'opportunistes', 'direction']},
               {'twAuthor': 'Nathalie Arthaud',
                'twMedium': 'Android',
                'nFav': '37',
                'nRT': '24',
                'isRT': False,
                'twText': ' #10mai Commemoration fin de l esclavage. Reste à supprimer l esclavage salarial defendu par #Macron et Hollande ',
                'twParty': 'Lutte Ouvrière',
                'cleanText': ' 10mai commemoration fin de l esclavage reste à supprimer l esclavage salarial defendu par macron et hollande ',
                'twToken': ['10mai', 'commemoration', 'fin', 'esclavage', 'reste', 'supprimer', 'esclavage', 'salarial', 'defendu', 'macron', 'hollande']
               }]
```

However, there are no reliable French lemmatizers in Python. So I used some resources to have my own French words lemmatizer dictionary. The dict looks like this:

```
sample_lemmas = [{"ortho":"rêves","lemme":"rêve","cgram":"NOM"},
                 {"ortho":"opportunistes","lemme":"opportuniste","cgram":"ADJ"},
                 {"ortho":"préfèrent","lemme":"préférer","cgram":"VER"},
                 {"ortho":"nouvelle","lemme":"nouveau","cgram":"ADJ"},
                 {"ortho":"allez","lemme":"aller","cgram":"VER"},
                 {"ortho":"défendu","lemme":"défendre","cgram":"VER"}]
```

So that `ortho` is the written form of a word (eg. *processed*), `lemme`is the lemmatized form of the word (eg. *process*) and `cgram` is the grammatical category of a word (eg *VER* for a verb).

So what I wanted to do was to create a `twLemmas` key for each tweet, which is a list of the lemmas derived from the `twToken` list. So I loop through each tweet in `sample_data`, then I loop through each token in `twToken`, see if the token exists in my lemmas dictionary `sample_lemmas`, and if it does, I retrieve the lemma from the `sample_lemmas` dictionary and add it to the list that will be fed in each `twLemmas` key. If it doesn't, I simply add the word to the list.

My code is the following :

```
list_of_ortho = []                      #List of words used to compare if a token doesn't exist in my lemmas dictionary
for wordDict in sample_lemmas:          #This loop feeds this list with each word
    list_of_ortho.append(wordDict["ortho"])

for elemList in sample_data:            #Here I iterate over each tweet in my data
    list_of_lemmas = []                 #This is the temporary list which will be the value to each twLemmas key
    for token in elemList["twToken"]:   #Here, I iterate over each token/word of a tweet
        for wordDict in sample_lemmas:
            if token == wordDict["ortho"]:
                list_of_lemmas.append(wordDict["lemme"])
        if token not in list_of_ortho:  #And this is to add a word to my list if it doesn't exist in my lemmas dictionary
            list_of_lemmas.append(token)
    elemList["lemmas"] = list_of_lemmas

sample_data
```

The loop works fine, however it takes about 4 hours to complete. Now I know I'm no programmer nor a Python expert, and I know that it will take time to complete no matter what. However, this is why I wanted to ask you if anyone had a better idea about how I could improve my code ?

Thank you if anyone can take the time to understand my code and help me. I hope I was clear enough (English is not my first language sorry).

Comment: and also, in Python we name functions and variables using `lower_case_with_underscores` not `camelCase`

Comment: You also want a lookup dict instead of list_of_ortho. It's doing a big loop for what should be a single check.

Comment: Wow, thank you for all these comments ! I won't have time to try it right now unfortunately but I'll try tonight... @KennyOstrom : Thank you, I knew it was partly on this side I was stupidly losing calculation performence. @ Boris : Thank you too ! I ignored the differences between lists and sets tbh... About the convention, I was told the opposite actually u.u" (I was told that the underscore convention was for R, not Python...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary that maps orthos to lemmes:

```
ortho_to_lemme = {word_dict["ortho"]: word_dict["lemme"] for word_dict in sample_lemmas}
for tweet in sample_data:
    tweet["twLemmas"] = [
        ortho_to_lemme.get(token, token) for token in tweet["twToken"]
    ]
```

Comment: The key here is the one-time setup of the dictionary outside the for loop, and of course its O(1) lookup. The original code is slow because it loops through all the lemmas, multiple times for each token.

Comment: I tried with a subset of my data and your response gives me impressive results :
- Time elapsed with the original loop : 30.78663806700206 
- Time elapsed with your loop : 0.23488750499745947

Comment: Edit : Just ran it on the whole dataset, took me 1.9920109320009942 seconds instead of ~3.5 hours ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Thank you for laying out your question so nicely and having runable code with sample data.